# In Corda, how can I set the logging level for flow tests?

Tags: corda

I am running flow tests in Corda and want to set the logging level to `debug` to see the SQL queries executed against the vault when I use `vaultService.queryBy`.

How can I set the logging level in flow tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the flow tests' logger settings by passing `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml` as a VM option.

For example, in the CorDapp Example (https://github.com/corda/samples), you could enable `debug`-level logging in flows by:

- Updating `config/test/log4j2.xml` to change the logging level from `info` to `debug`
- Modifying the `VM options` setting of the `Run Flow Tests - Java` run configuration to `-ea -javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=../config/test/log4j2.xml`