# How do I control the Log level from INFO to WARN when running a MockNetwork with several StartedMockNode's

Tags: corda

When I am performing tests with a MockNetwork I get lots of INFO level logs.  How do I change that so I only see WARN level logs?

I have read other articles for changing logging on running nodes...

[link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295927/can-i-finely-control-logging-by-corda-nodes)

[link #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305928/how-to-stop-node-from-logging-node-conf-during-startup)

...but editing the log4j2.xml file doesn't seem to affect StartedMockNode's running on a MockNetwork (or I am doing it wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the flow tests' logger settings by passing -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml as a VM option.

To add VM option in Intellij, Run -> Edit Configurations -> VM Options in the flow test
Refer this link [[In Corda, how can I set the logging level for flow tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262113/in-corda-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-for-flow-tests])

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me.  Note sure what I am doing wrong. Step 1: Change the `log4j2.xml` and set all instances of `info` to `warn`. Step 2: Add `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=F:\corda\Java\javaTemplate\config\test\log4j2.xml` to the VM options in Intellij for the Gradle test I am running.  Step 3: Run the test. I can tell my changes are having no effect because I still get all the `INFO` logs.  I've changed the name of the log file in the `log4j2.xml` file  but it's still writing to the old one.  If you can think of anything else I might be doing wrong let me know.

Comment: Try removing .idea folder and re-importing the project.

Comment: That was worth a try but unfortunately it made no difference.  I tried a bunch of things yesterday - different file location, different file name, different methods to locate the file (URI etc.).  I have got to be missing something simple or it's something different with Windows maybe.  I'll try so more things today.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shivaganesh's answer is correct as is Joel's original [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262113/in-corda-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-for-flow-tests]).

However what I found was it only works for me if I am using JUnit for testing.  If I switch to the Gradle Test Runner it doesn't seem to work.  I've posted a new question clarifying the issue: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457132/how-to-control-log-level-when-using-gradle-test-runner)