# How to control log level when using Gradle Test Runner

Tags: corda

My Setup:

- OS:       Windows 10
- Corda:        4.1 (I always start with the template.)
- IDE:      IntelliJ 2019.1.3
- Language:     Java

In 2018 Joel wrote how to control logging levels when performing Flow tests: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262113/in-corda-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-for-flow-tests])

*You can override the flow tests' logger settings by passing:*

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml
```

*...as a VM option*

This works great if you are using JUnit in IntelliJ.
However, the Corda documentation recommends that you use the Gradle Test Runner to perform tests: [link](https://docs.corda.net/head/testing.html#running-tests-in-intellij)

When I switch to using the Gradle Test Runner the same VM Option has no effect on the logging levels.

How do I control the logging level if I am using the Gradle Test Runner?

Comment: Facing the same issue with the gradle runner; log4j2.xml changes are not detected by the gradle runner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j config file would be picked up from the test resources. Also the default filename Gradle looks for in case of test cases is: `log4j2-test.xml`.

Make sure you have the sourceSets right in your build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    test{
        resources {
            srcDir 'config/test'
        }
    }
}
```

Above is only for the test resources, please add others as applicable.

`log4j2-test.xml` file should be available in the `config/test` folder, else the default log4j2-test.xml present inside corda-test-common.jar is picked up (I suppose).